# 2 SMPS connected together for ground shifting

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, step-down

I have two SMPS of same manufacturer.

**FOLLOWING ARE THERE DETAILS:**

MANUFACTURER: Maa-Ku

MODEL: S-24v-5a

INPUT : 240V AC

OUTPUT : 24V 5A DC

WATT : 120 W

Product link: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07B2RXK4C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I have a requirement where the board needs input of 24-0-24 5A.

Following is my general idea for neccessary schematic:

[image]

As i am a beginner, I want to confirm the schematic will provide me 24-0-24 5A DC in output ? 
If not, can some one suggest article for the same ?

Comment: You have omitted the make, mode and datasheet link for the power supplies. The answer all depends on whether the outputs are isolated from earth or not. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Comment: This will work if the power supplies are isolated, and it will break your power supplies if they're not.

Comment: @Transistor I have added product link.

Comment: Unfortunately that's just a link to an Amazon catalog page. We get a lot of tech support questions here for cheap stuff bought on Amazon, etc. Our motto is, "No datasheet? No sale!"

Comment: OK, as the SMPS is ready-made product, i did not found the datasheet for particular smps. :(

Comment: Dead in the water with no oars and a sail (nor performance guarantee) without a data sheet. Generally speaking, in EE, engineers will only consider a product if it comes with a bona fide data sheet from a reputable manufacturer supplied through a reputable dealer who simultaneously is reputable at supplying the type of product in question I.e. just because a dealer might be reputable for selling pens or paper doesn’t mean they have cred selling chips.

Comment: @Andyaka Completely agreed. Let me follow your suggestion and ask the details for datasheet from the manufacturer.

Comment: Then you need to establish that the manufacturer is reputable but, you still have to wonder about amazon’s role in all of this and who the real supplier is and whether that real supplier is reputable and not building locally a power supply that might be dangerous or defective as a copy of the original manufacturer.